# Multiplicative digital root and multiplicative persistence

Tags: python

I wrote the below code to figure out multiplicative digital root and multplicative persistence. I am clear about multiplicative digital root but have a question on multiplicative persistence (MP).

In the below code, there are two while loops and to find MP have put a counter incrementing everytime the multiplication happens.

MP differs when the line `count += 1` was included in inner while loop and when kept in outer while loop.

Output when `count += 1` is in the outer loop is `222 :  [8, 3]`

Now my question is which is correct for Muliplicative persistence.

Have referred https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Digital_root/Multiplicative_digital_root and as per this `count += 1` is in the outer loop and the output is `222 :  [8, 1]`

Can anyone please suggest which is one is correct?

```
    def mdr_mp(num):
    '''
    This function computes the multiplicative digital root and multiplicative persistence of a given number
    '''
    product = 1
    mdr = num
    count = 0

    #Find mdr and persistence 
    while mdr > 9: #as long as mdr is > 9 
        while num > 0: #as long as quotient is > 0 
            #use divmod fn to return the quotient and remainder of num when divided by 10
            num, number = divmod(num, 10)
            product *= number #perform product of each digit in the number
            count += 1
        mdr = product #set product to mdr so as to check if it is > 9 else repeat
        num = product #set product to num so as to perform the product again
        product = 1 #initialize product to 1 so that product of the new num can be computed
        #count += 1 #multiplicative persistence 

    return [mdr, count] #returns multiplicative digital root and multiplicative persistence as a list

    num = 222
    #Function call returns list of number containing mdr and mp
    print("Number: (MDR, MP)")
    list1 = mdr_mp(num)
    print(num, ": ", list1)

Output:
    Number: (MDR, MP)
    222 :  [8, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

for 222, the `(mdr, mp)` is `(8, 1)`. -> 2*2*2 = 8 done in one loop.

for 34, the `(mdr, mp)` is `(2, 2)`. -> 3*4 = 12. 1*2 = 2. done in 2 loops.

programmatically:

```
def get_mdr_and_mp(number):
    time_multiplied = 0
    current_mdr = number
    while current_mdr > 9:
        current_mdr = multiply_all_digits(current_mdr)
        times_multiplied += 1
    return current_mdr, times_multiplied
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go another simplified form of code:

```
 def mula(a):
        mul=1
        for i in str(a):
            mul=mul*int(i)
        mul+=1
        return (mul-1)

    c=int(input("Enter a number"))

    cnt=0
    while c>=10:
        c=mula(c)
        cnt+=1
    print("MDR:{}  MPer:{}".format(c,cnt))
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. This provided answer may be correct, but **it could benefit from an explanation**. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).